# Elastic Search Routing didnt work all of sudden

Tags: elasticsearch

I am elastic 6.8 and routing doesnt seem work. Example I used ,

```
PUT my_index/_doc/2?routing="user1" 
{
  "title": "This is a document"
}

{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_version" : 2,
  "result" : "updated",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

On applying `GET` query

```
GET my_index/_doc/2?routing="user1"
```

No results . It looks strange, Am i missing something ?

```
{
  "_index" : "my_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "found" : false
}
```

**Update #1**

the following API results in error ( taken from documentation ))

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1?routing=user1&refresh=true 
{
  "title": "This is a document"
}

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown value for refresh: [true ]."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown value for refresh: [true ]."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are getting this below error because you have added 1 or 2 whitespace characters at the end of `refresh=true` in the `PUT my_index/_doc/1?routing=user1&refresh=true`**

```
 {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown value for refresh: [true ]."
  }
```

From elasticsearch source code:

```
if ("".equals(value)) {
                // Empty string is IMMEDIATE because that makes "POST /test/test/1?refresh" perform
                // a refresh which reads well and is what folks are used to.
                return IMMEDIATE;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value for refresh: [" + value + "].");
```

**Remove the whitespace from the end, and then try indexing the document again**

Adding a working example:

**Index Data:**

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/{{index-name}}/_doc/1?routing=user1&refresh=true

{
    "name":"multi grain bread"
}
```

In response, you will get

```
{
  "_index": "64762507",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "result": "created",
  "forced_refresh": true,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1
}
```

**When retrieving the document using**

`GET http://localhost:9200/{{index-name}}/_doc/1?routing=user1`

In response, you will get :

```
{
  "_index": "64762507",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "_seq_no": 0,
  "_primary_term": 1,
  "_routing": "user1",
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "name": "multi grain bread"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does refresh is mandatory attribute when passing routing field  ? pplease check passing the routing field without passing refresh

Comment: @Nag `refresh` is not a mandatory attribute when passing the routing field.  And even you should not add `?refresh=true` to each indexing operation as it can slow down the indexing.

Comment: @Nag **`refresh` is added so that it can refresh the relevant primary and replica shards (not the whole index) immediately after the operation occurs, so that the updated document appears in search results immediately.** Please go through this doc to know more about `?refresh` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-refresh.html

Comment: @Nag please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :)

Comment: that is true, but i am wondering why the query didn't return the results ( from the question I originally posted )